# Sublime text Key bindings for multiple cursors

Tags: sublimetext3

I've created a simple .py plugin for my sublime, which outputs just a timestamp with prefix and I want to insert it in each of my multiple cursor position.

Plugin:

```
import datetime
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TimestampcondencedCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    val = "%s" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("am_func_%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
    self.view.insert(edit, self.view.sel()[0].begin(), val)
```

And key binding:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+z"], "command": "timestampcondenced"}
```

[image]

It works, but when I hit `ctrl+shift+z` only first cursor affected, which is pity.
I want to have it for all my cursors, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `view.sel()` returns a list of all of the selections, but your code is explicitly using only the first one (the `[0]` in `view.sel()[0]`).

In order to insert at all all of the cursor positions you just need to loop over all of the selections instead:

```python
import datetime
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class TimestampcondencedCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    val = "%s" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("am_func_%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
    for sel in self.view.sel():
        self.view.insert(edit, sel.begin(), val)
```

Comment: or just `view.run_command('insert', { 'characters': val })` which will automatically insert the specified characters at all the text caret locations